# javascript creating div element and adding contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a div element and add few contents to it and need to display the contents of the div element once everything is added.

Im using the below code and for some reason the div element is not being displayed in HTML...

http://jsfiddle.net/KVe9K/

**js code**

```
container = $("<div/>", { "class": "container" });
$(".container").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
$(".container").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
$(".container").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
$(".container").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
$(".container").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
```

**css code:**

```
.container{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery (and you seem to be), tag the question `jquery`.

Answer (score 3):

> for some reason the div element is not being displayed in HTML...

That's because you never put `container` anywhere in the DOM. You've created the element, but not added it to the page anywhere.

Add it to the page where you want it to be. For instance, this adds it to the `body` element:

```
container.appendTo(document.body);
```

...but you're likely to have some other specific place you want it to be.

Also note that your fiddle isn't working because you didn't include jQuery, so `$` is an undefined symbol.

Here's a fiddle that *includes jQuery*, and appends the element to the DOM: http://jsfiddle.net/KVe9K/1/

---

If you mean, why aren't your `append` calls working, it's because the element isn't in the DOM yet, so it doesn't match the `.container` selector. You can do this, though:

```
container = $("<div/>", { "class": "container" });
container.append("<b>Appended text</b>");
container.append("<b>Appended text</b>");
container.append("<b>Appended text</b>");
container.append("<b>Appended text</b>");
container.append("<b>Appended text</b>");
container.appendTo(document.body); // Or whereever
```

[Further updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KVe9K/2/)

Comment: @TJ: Thanks..The only that is missing in your response is how to get the content of the div element...I will edit the question now

Comment: @user1050619: That's not what the question seems to ask. Don't edit a question to ask a completely different question than it originally asked, at least not once you have answers addressing what you actually asked.

Comment: @user1050619: ...but I've updated the answer based on your statement you wanted to show it *after* the text was appended.

Answer (score 0):

```
container = $("<div/>", { "class": "container" });
```

This like doesn't add div to the dom element.